# How to make pjax:popstate work like a simple PJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, pjax, popstate

While using the popstate in pjax, I want the content to be loaded from the server again, instead of being replaced by cached content of the browser. If the cached content is being applied, the `<script>` inside the cached content is not at all working. So, is there any way to force a normal PJAX call to the server instead of using the cached data, when we simply hit the browser's Back/Forward buttons?

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully notice line **476 to 491** in the file **jquery.pjax.js** here in this link: [jQuery PJAX by Chris Wanstrath (defunkt)](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js). The codes under the `if` actually calls the **Cached Contents** and the code under the `else` portion is what we only want.

```
  if (contents) {
    container.trigger('pjax:start', [null, options])

    pjax.state = state
    if (state.title) document.title = state.title
    var beforeReplaceEvent = $.Event('pjax:beforeReplace', {
      state: state,
      previousState: previousState                                                     
    })                                                                                 
    container.trigger(beforeReplaceEvent, [contents, options])                         
    container.html(contents)

    container.trigger('pjax:end', [null, options])
  } else {
      pjax(options)
  }
```

So, now you know what we are going to do! Yes, just remove everything except this line:

```
    pjax(options)
```

and you're good to go! It's strange that nobody gave me this solution. However, I've finally found a solution by myself, and I think this will help a lot of people.

Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify the source. You can configure pjax to load from the server again, instead of using the cache by setting its `maxCacheLength` to 0

`$.pjax.defaults.maxCacheLength = 0;`